Euler-Maclaurin method of integration
I am trying to calculate the following integral using the Euler-Maclaurin formula. However, when
a and  are not integers but real numbers, defining the sum, for example, between 1/3 and 1/2, doesn't make sense and makes the formula valid only for integer  and b. Unless another strategy is employed, this causes problems. Can you suggest an alternative approach?
I try this but do not work
f[x_] := Cos[x ] (*Replace with your function*)

(*Limits of integration a and b*)
a = 1/2;
b = 1/3;

(*Number of terms to consider in the series*)
nMax = 10;

(*Split the integral into segments*)
aFloor = Floor[a];
aFrac = a - aFloor;
bFloor = Floor[b];
bFrac = b - bFloor;

(*Calculate the fractional parts separately*)
integralFractional = 
  NIntegrate[f[x], {x, a, aFloor + 1}] + 
   NIntegrate[f[x], {x, bFloor, b}];

(*Calculate the sum of f[j] from aFloor+1 to bFloor-1*)
sumTerm = Sum[f[j], {j, aFloor + 1, bFloor - 1}];

(*Calculate the correction terms using the Bernoulli numbers*)
correctionTerm = 
  1/2 (f[aFloor + 1] + f[bFloor]) + 
   Sum[BernoulliB[
       2 k]/(2 k)!*(D[f[x], {x, 2 k - 1}] /. 
        x -> bFloor - D[f[x], {x, 2 k - 1}] /. x -> aFloor + 1), {k, 
     1, nMax}];

(*Apply Euler-Maclaurin formula to the integer parts*)
integralInteger = sumTerm - correctionTerm;

(*Total integral value*)
integralTotal = integralFractional + integralInteger

(*Display the result*)
NIntegrate[f[x], {x, a, b}]
`


See Weisstein, Eric W. "Euler-Maclaurin Integration Formulas." From MathWorld for info.

but if a=0.23 b=0.34 and use the second formula from the page above I do not know how tabulate the function??
